# Error getting NanoAppRegistry workspace info error?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am working iPhone application using native iOS SDK. when i run and then hit my web service means i am getting this following error. why this error coming in my iPhone device. I am using iPhone 6. It is occurring only in iPhone device not in simulator. Give me some solution how to solve this error

> Error getting NanoAppRegistry workspace info: Error
>   Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)" (The connection to service named
>   com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated.)
>   UserInfo=0x145605c90 {NSDebugDescription=The connection to service
>   named com.apple.nanoappregistry.workspace was invalidated.

Thanks in Advance.